# Regex match section within string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a string `foo-foo-AB1234-foo-AB12345678`. The string can be in any format, is there a way of matching only the following pattern *letter,letter,digits 3-5* ?

I have the following implementation:

```
preg_match_all('/[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{3,6}/', $string, $matches);
```

Unfortunately this finds a match on `AB1234` AND `AB12345678` which has more than 6 digits. I only wish to find a match on `AB1234` in this instance.

I tried:

```
preg_match_all('/^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{3,6}$/', $string, $matches);
```

You will notice `^` and `$` to mark the beginning and end, but this only applies to the string, not the section, therefore no match is found.

I understand why the code is behaving like it is. It makes logical sense. I can't figure out the solution though.

Comment: you can use this [a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be looking for word boundaries `\b`:

```
\b\p{L}{2}\p{N}{3,5}\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eF3aR9/1)

Note that `\p{L}` matches a Unicode letter, and `\p{N}` matches a Unicode number.

You can as well use your modified regex `\b[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3,5}\b`. Note that using anchors makes your regex match only at the beginning of a string (with `^`) or/and at the end of the string (with `$`).

In case you have underscored words (like `foo-foo_AB1234_foo_AB12345678_string`), you will need a [slight modification](https://regex101.com/r/eF3aR9/2):

```
(?<=\b|_)\p{L}{2}\p{N}{3,5}(?=\b|_)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did try the `word boundaries` implementation but not to this extent. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to end your regular expression with a pattern for a non-digit. In Java this would be `\D`, this should be the same in PHP.